# Ubuntu server does not accept any request from outside

Tags: networking, 14.04, 16.04, server, iptables

I have a database in ubuntu server, and it works on server, the port is 5436.However, I can not connect it from outside.

I use ufw order

it lists as below

```
[17] 5436 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[18] 5436/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I use netstat

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5436            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

I have tested simple python host, it had same problem. Ubuntu server does not accept any request from outside
How can I fix this?

Comment: how and especially from where do you connect to ubuntu?

Comment: i use dbeaver, but when i set python host, i used web browser , it did not work. I

Comment: Assuming this is PostgreSQL, have you also configured the database to listen on the non-standard port number? 

Comment: yes, I did @matigo

Comment: define "from outside".  Do you mean frmo outside your network or outside your server?  Is this server a VPS or similar on Digital Ocean or some other platform or on your own home network?\

Comment: @ThomasWard  outside server.  On the same network also it does not accept any request.  It is like server is isolated from outside.    I used ngork port forwarding then it worked only in LAN

Comment: Your ufw seemt to show only IPv6 ... are your client configured for IPv6 or have you tried to enable IPv4 in ufw too ?

Comment: @SorenA, I tried ufw allow port , it didn't work do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The UFW rules you showed are valid for IPv6 protocol, not for IPv4.
Check your IPv4 rules, i.e. ones which do not include `(v6)` mark.

Your database listening port TCP 5434 is IPv4 type port, but the firewall rules are IPv6 type.